# Problem with marginfigure

Tags: floats, captions, sidenotes

Refer to my mwe, the marginfigure works just fine. All labels are left align.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx,kantlipsum,multicol}
\usepackage[papersize={21cm,23cm},top=1.8cm, bottom=2cm, outer=7cm, inner=2cm, heightrounded, marginparwidth=5.0cm, marginparsep=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{l3keys2e}
\usepackage{changepage}
%\usepackage{keyfloat}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
%\captionsetup[subfigure]{
%   justification=centering,
%   labelfont={normalsize},
%   font={normalsize},
%}

%==========================================
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter 1}
    \section{Section 1}
    \begin{marginfigure}[0cm]
        \begin{subfigure}{\marginparwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a.jpg}%
            \subcaption{A}\label{example-image-a.jpg}%
        \end{subfigure} 
        \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b.jpg}%
            \subcaption{B}\label{example-image-b.jpg}%
        \end{subfigure}     
        \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c.jpg}%
            \subcaption{C}\label{example-image-c.jpg}%
        \end{subfigure}
        %       \captionsetup{font=Large,justification=centering}
        \caption{xxx}
    \end{marginfigure}
\end{document}
```

[image: leftaligned caption]      [image]     [image]

When I want them to be at the center, I uncommented `\captionsetup`, the subsfigure a, b, and c are aligned at the center but the "Figure 1.1: xxx" was not. I have to add `\captionsetup` before `\end{marginfigure}` to make that happened. I want to do that globally instead of locally. How can I do that?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to globally center the `marginfigure`'s caption horizontally, you can use `\DeclareCaptionStyle{marginfigure}` as shown in the following MWE. The declaration of the font size originates in the definition in the `sidenotes` package.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[papersize={21cm,23cm},top=1.8cm, bottom=2cm, outer=7cm, inner=2cm, heightrounded, marginparwidth=5.0cm, marginparsep=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{
   justification=centering,
   labelfont={normalsize},
   font={normalsize},
}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{marginfigure}{font=footnotesize,justification=centering}

%==========================================
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter 1}
    \section{Section 1}
    \begin{marginfigure}[0cm]
        \begin{subfigure}{\marginparwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a.jpg}%
            \subcaption{A}\label{example-image-a.jpg}%
        \end{subfigure} 
        \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b.jpg}%
            \subcaption{B}\label{example-image-b.jpg}%
        \end{subfigure}     
        \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c.jpg}%
            \subcaption{C}\label{example-image-c.jpg}%
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{xxx}
    \end{marginfigure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: where is defined `marginfigure`?

Comment: @Zarko: The `marginfigure` environment is defined in the `sidenotes` package.

Comment: thank you very much! i'm not familiar with `sidenotes` ...

Comment: @Zarko: You're welcome. Before seeing this question, I wasn't familiar with this package either.

Comment: @leandriis: Thanks for your code. Which page can i find the definition of DeclareCaptionStyle?. I want to learn more about the other options.

Comment: @kmmm: `\DeclareCaptionStyle` is described in chapter '4. Own Enhancements' of the [caption package](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption).